Classicthesis odd/even margins
I have a question about the page margins in the classicthesis template.
The question itself is not directly related to LaTeX, but I don't know where else to ask.
The classicthesis template uses a larger margin on the left for the even numbered pages and larger margin on the right for odd numbered pages. This way the large margins are on the outside.
You can see this in their template:

I wonder why this is the case. Intuitively I'd expect the larger margins to be on the inside, since this is where the pages meet and you have a 'risk' of making it a bit harder to read to the curvature of the pages.
I am aware that I can swap the odd/even margin, but there is probably a good reason why it is done this way which I simply don't understand.

Usually these are the layout settings of the pages how you see it. If you need additional margins when bounding the paper, you should arrange the page on the (usually larger) paper accordingly. Some packages, provide additional parameters for this, e.g., geometry or typearea. Or you can use additional packages like crop. And yes, it is common that the outer margin is larger than each part of the inner margin, because the inner margin of the left and right page build together the complete inner margin, that becomes therefore larger.


the outer margin is used for margin notes, 2) when the two pages are viewed together, as in a book, the inner white space gets almost doubled, 3) there's already a BCOR of 5 mm applied to account for the white space lost by binding.

